# Quasar throws 3 errors in import-quasar.js after quasar dev command

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework, quasar

The error below is generated after quasar dev mat command. Its a fresh installation 
after

```
-Autoimport option
-cd project-name
-npm i
-quasar dev mat 

Anyone help?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMm9N.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/2739/upgrading-v0-16-to-v0-17/13): you should change

`import Quasar from 'quasar'` to `import { Quasar } from 'quasar'`